# What is the difference between b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton); and b= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

Tags: android

b is the object of Button class 
Someplaces  use of view.findViewById is must

Comment: use view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton) where view is the viewGroup and R.id.mybutton is its child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you write:

```
b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

it is use directly to your layout

but if you write:

```
b= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

it is use for inflate layout(Custom Layout)

for example in: 
Custom Dialog

Custom Layout for Listview that is extend of BaseAdapter ,ArrayAdapter ,....
and it is for connect to Layoutinflater

Answer (score 2):

```
findViewById
```

is a method. Sometimes you can reference like this:

```
b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

which is shorthand for this:

```
b=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

The IDE (Android Studio or whatever) understands that `findViewById` is a method because it is being called in an object that has (or "implements") that method. However, this is a method that a lot of objects implement. So, if you want to "find a view using the 'R' id" sometimes you want to find it from another object besides the one making the call.

For example, an `Activity` implements this method. But if you have a `View` in the `Activity` (like a row in a list) and you want to retrieve values from that row, you would do something like:

```
b=(Button) myRowView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

In this case, `myRowView` is something on the screen that should have a button with an id of "mybutton". If you don't tell the IDE/compiler to check the "row" inside the `Activity` then it will assume that you are trying to find a view that is directly defined in the `Activity`. That might work, but if you have 50 rows, and all of them have buttons with the same id, you probably won't get the right one... but when you specify *which row* by specifying the object, then you get the correct one.

The key here is that a method can be called without the keyword `this` and so it looks somewhat "magical" at times.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you declare button directly from your layout you write this:
   b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
else if you inflate any layout to your activity you should write this:
 View view;
 LayoutInflater subCatHead = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 view = subCatHead.inflate(R.layout.sub_cat_headerlyt, null);

  b= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity if you declare button directly write this:

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

In Case of Custom Adapter 
else if you inflate any layout to your activity should write this:

```
button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

**In Custom array Adapter**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog_stage_item, parent, false);
        mStageListModel = null;
        mStageListModel = (BlogStageDetailDTO) data.get(position);

        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_spinner_item);

        // Set values for spinner each row
        label.setText(mStageListModel.getStage_name());



        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use directly activity Layout then Use

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

and when Use custom Layout like `Base adapter, Arrayadapter, Fragment` you have to pass main container view like and called

```
button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

Answer (score 0):

b= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
it is used when you use inflater layout or  you are trying to access a widget in a fragment as the fragment does not have a direct information about the view . It first need to get the information about the root view .